# Can't center a ul with css

Tags: css

Guys I'm trying to center this simple ul here. Any idea on whats wrong ?

Css:

```
ul {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

JSP/HTML:

> ```
> <ul>
>         <li>Login</li>
>         <li>Option2</li>
>         <li>Optino3</li>
>     </ul>
> ```

Comment: First, I think this question would fit better in doctype or stackoverflow. Also it lacks of more description, perhaps a screenshot...

Comment: Correct. HTMLCSS questions belong on [Doctype](http://doctype.com) as per the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Because even though the `ul` centers (with the margin: auto) it's a block element so it spans the entire width of the element. There is no room for margin on either side of it, you'll have to specify a width for the `ul` element for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/2 it has many HTML/CSS articles.

**EDIT**

Again, nothing against being downvoted. But knowing **why** downvotes (as well as upvotes, unless it is really really obvious) is important indeed to everyone, including me.

Despite the question best fits in other forum (yeah, I commented on question first), I tried a nice reply as per QA seems to be a beginner. And for beginners, I think the best is not just solve the problem, but learn the basics.